# Google Maps V3: Comparing the distance of multiple points

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to create a Google map which automatically calculates the distance between a number of different points.

For example:
I have map and 3 points A-shop1, B-shop2, and C-customer. I want to show on one map distance between point C --> A, and second distance from point C --> B (not step, two difrent road). I want to show which store is closer.

thx

Comment: can you get the long and lat of the points?

Comment: And what about point B to point C?  What are you doing to differentiate your points?  Would be helpful to see what code you've come up with so far

Comment: ok I'll describe the problem a little closer. I integrated Oracle BI 10g with Google maps v3. I built report witch showed:
lat | lng | city | store_manager | store | etc.| 
On map I add point: store_manager and Store. Generally all shops have manager :) but some times manager is fired :) and shop stay without a guardian :). I must show on the map distance between shop --> all showed manager on map. System should suggest the shortes road and then boss can decied witch shop are connected which manager :P 

Sorry for my english. 
@ducan
And what about point B to point C - not needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use google's distance matrix api. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/